# Initialization of a C++ member with type unordered_map<vector<int>, int>

Tags: c++, class, vector, unordered-map

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

class Testclass{
public:
    explicit Testclass();
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::vector<int>, int> world;
};

Testclass::Testclass() {
    std::vector<int> temp;
    world = {{temp,0}};
}

int main()
{
    Testclass testclass();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program above, the complier prompts that

```
error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::hash<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > >'
```

I know that there are some problem with the initilzation in of the class memeber "world". But I just had no idea of how to initialize it. I tried to specifiy the size of the "temp", but it did not work.

Could anyone help me solving the problem? Thanks.

Comment: You have to give `unordered_map` a custom hash function which can handle `std::vector`s, since the default one apparently is unable to so.

Comment: Incidentally, `Testclass testclass();` is a function declaration, not a variable declaration.